# Unable to access the Settings in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1-preview

I recently applied the Windows 8.1 update. Everything went fine, except I can no longer access the Settings 'app' via the Start Srceen - I just get a blank screen or get sent back to the Start screen

If I create a new account, it works fine - just not my account.

The Event Log points me to Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational where I get the message

> The application windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy!microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel is not registered for the Windows.Launch contract or is not installed.

But struggling to find a solution to it. Found a couple of references online, but most seemed to relate to Domain based accounts and Group Policies, but I'm on a Microsoft / Local account.

Ran CHKDSK & System File Checker - but this didn't do anything either

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason part of Windows Store apps became "unregistered" after Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 upgrade. I was able to get the "PC Settings" functionality back by running this command:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted add-appxpackage -register $Env:SystemRoot\ImmersiveControlPanel\appxmanifest.xml –DisableDevelopmentMode
```

which registers the PC Settings up again. Note that I also had to do the similar exercise for other apps too, most notably Windows Store itself.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed mine too. Do you have a list of the commands you run to get each app working? I don't know what to change in the command for each app.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that worked for me here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6f119828-dd1b-42da-b8b5-c6e6c0d5617c/no-apps-or-windows-store-work-after-upgrading-to-windows-81-enterprise?forum=w8itproinstall

> 1. **Fixing the app store**:
>
>    1. Open registry editor typing regedit.exe from a command line.
>    2. Browse to the registry key at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\appmodel\repository\packages`.
>    3. Right click on the `packages` key and bring up the “Permissions” tab.
>    4. Click the “Advanced” button located at the bottom right corner.
>    5. Check to see the account name that shows up as the “Owner” (this is the first line of text on the “advanced security settings” dialog
>         for the “packages” key). It should say `SYSTEM`.  (For me this showed
>         the built-in local Administrators group)
>    6. If it is any other account, click on the “Change” button next to it.
>    7. Type `SYSTEM` in the “select user” dialog. If “Multiple Names Found” window comes up, select the row for `SYSTEM`.
>    8. Click OK to the dialogs and close them all.
>    9. Run from admin command prompt: `Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register
>         $Env:SystemRoot\WinStore\AppxManifest.xml`
> 2. **Fixing all modern apps**:
>
>    Run from admin PowerShell:
>
>    `((Get-ChildItem
>      "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\InboxApplications") | Get-ItemProperty).Path | Add-AppxPackage -Register -DisableDevelopmentMode`
>
>    - When I ran this the black X persisted until after the next step and reboot.  But trying to start an app gives me a new message and a
>        link to the store.
> 3. **Fixing 3rd party apps**:
>
>    Delete the regkey:
>      `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\[UserSid]`
> 4. **Restart**.
>
>    After a reboot the apps still showed the black X for a minute or so,
>      but it soon cleared up on its own and all apps seemed to be working
>      again.  I was also able to update the apps from the app store once
>      signing in with a Microsoft account.  Finally, I am again able to get
>      into PC Settings.