# Windows 10 start menu item name missing

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu

Can somebody tell me why my settings menu looks like a bunch of weird text. Please tell how can I fix this.

[image: Windows 10 Start Menu]

Comment: Run `cmd` as administrator and write `sfc /scannow`

Comment: Have you attempted to disable any Widows Feature using any tools or commands?

Comment: No I did not try to disable any Windows feature. I'm a default loving guy.

Comment: @spherical_dog I got the message `Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations`.

Comment: This might be worth trying. http://superuser.com/a/685726/532997

Comment: @spherical_dog The answer you pointed to didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`?